# How to divide text into several parts relative to one character

Tags: string, python-2.7, split

How to separate text from "^" to "^" and save data to different variables
Below I insert what is the main problem:

DM^126287^8209/2018^INLMDU 39942^70

It will often be the case that the number of characters between "^" will change, so I have to read from the character to the character.

Do you  have any ideas?

I know how to check in which cell the sign is located, the code is presented below:

```
currentWord = "DM^126287^8209/2018^INLMDU 39942^70"
guess = "^"
occurrences = currentWord.count(guess)
indices = [i for i, a in enumerate(currentWord)
           if a == guess]

print indices
```

But it needs to save "8209/2018" to the variable, "INLMDU 39942" to the next variable and "70" to the last variable

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try: `"DM^126287^8209/2018^INLMDU 39942^70".split('^')` ?

Comment: No, I have not tried, I'm already looking.

Comment: Thank you,Maurice Meyer, they work as it should